# how to silently "Save All Buffers" in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How do I create a command to "Silently Save All Buffers" in Aquamacs Emacs?

I found the command `save-some-buffers` which is nice, but the problem is that it prompts me, separately, to confirm every buffer I want to save.

Through Googling I found some documentation on a variable called `save-silently-p` but that doesn't seem to exist (in Aquamacs version 2.4, i.e. Emacs 23.3.50.1).

So how do I get it to save all buffers silently without prompting?

Comment: All you need is `C-u C-x s`

Comment: or `C-x s !` (which is clear simply from looking at the `C-h` help provided for the prompt options).

Comment: @phils very true, really no idea why the accepted answer needed to be so complicated.  `C-x s` and then `!` isn't "silent" and requires reaction to a prompt, (sorry pedantic.) - `C-u` is useful to know because it can provide additional functionality to a lot of things. Try `C-u` and `M-x align-regexp` for example.

Comment: Slomojo: You're quite right of course, but it seemed worth pointing out anyway, as it's the same number of keystrokes, and all the other interactive options remain available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this example, the *first* argument is set to a `non-nil` value -- "*[o]ptional argument (the prefix) `non-nil` means save all with no questions.*"  Although it could be just plain old `t`, I chose to make up a more meaningful symbol to remind myself of what it stands for -- i.e., `'no-confirm`.  If I wanted to receive a confirmation dialog, then I would instead use `nil` for the *first* argument.  See the doc-string -- `M-x describe-function RET save-some-buffers RET` -- for additional information regarding how this function behaves depending upon whether the *first* argument is `nil` or `non-nil`.

The example below uses `save-some-buffers` with a custom *zero argument function* for the *second* argument -- i.e, **PRED** -- to choose which buffers should be saved.  The doc-string for `save-some-buffers` states that the *second* argument -- i.e., **PRED** -- may be one of three possibilities -- **(1)** If **PRED** is `nil`, all the file-visiting buffers are considered; **(2)** If **PRED** is `t`, then *certain* non-file buffers will also be considered; or **(3)** If PRED is *a zero-argument function,* it indicates for each buffer whether to consider it or not when called with that buffer current.

The example uses a keyboard shortcut of `f5`, but the user is free to call this custom function interactively -- `M-x my-save-some-buffers` -- or assign a different keyboard shortcut entirely.  There are a few possible matches that have been hard-coded, and the user is free to add/remove/modify the conditions:

•  file-visiting-buffer **+** the file name matches the value of the variable `abbrev-file-name`.

• file-visiting-buffer **+** the major-mode is `latex-mode` from the built-in `tex-mode.el` -- *not* AUCTeX.

• file-visiting-buffer **+** the major-mode is `markdown-mode`.

• file-visiting-buffer **+** the major-mode is `emacs-lisp-mode`.

• file-visiting-buffer **+** the derived-mode is `org-mode`.

```
(defun my-save-some-buffers ()
(interactive)
  (save-some-buffers 'no-confirm (lambda ()
    (cond
      ((and buffer-file-name (equal buffer-file-name abbrev-file-name)))
      ((and buffer-file-name (eq major-mode 'latex-mode)))
      ((and buffer-file-name (eq major-mode 'markdown-mode)))
      ((and buffer-file-name (eq major-mode 'emacs-lisp-mode)))
      ((and buffer-file-name (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)))))))

(global-set-key [f5] 'my-save-some-buffers)
```

Answer (score 28):

There's no need to set any custom variables, you simply:

```
C-u C-x s
```

Or in long-hand:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>

In addition you can just do, `C-x s` and press `!` at the prompt answer yes to for all saveable file buffers. Which isn't strictly silent, but it's still very fast/unobstrusive. (credit: @phils)

Comment: Still, that requires pressing six keys. Much easier to click just two keys. I used Brian Burns's answer and bound the function `save-all` to `M-p`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. `C-x s` is bound to `save-some-buffers`, `C-u` provides it with the `t` as per Brian's `defun`.  I think it's fine to great that you want to add that to your `.emacs`.  It's worth remembering this method if you ever use an Emacs site that isn't yours.

Comment: A problem with `C-x s !` is the prompt only shows up when you have modified buffers, so it's not deterministic. It's a UX "synchronization barrier" which breaks the editing flow.

Comment: C-u C-x s - is what you should prefer then @hraban ... Not sure what your point is.  There's no flow barrier.

Comment: I'm replying to the last paragraph which could be interpreted as equivocating `C-x s !` with `C-u C-x s`. Someone might reasonably misunderstand that, so I thought I'd help out and provide a clarification. Maybe somebody else finds that useful. I hope that's ok.

Comment: Yes it's worth pointing out they are slightly different if that's unclear the answer can be edited.

Answer (score 19):

If you pass non-nil to `save-some-buffers` it will save all files without prompting, so you can do something like

```
(defun save-all () (interactive) (save-some-buffers t))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S") 'save-all)
```

Answer (score 3):

From the info page of `save-some-buffers`:

> (save-some-buffers &optional ARG PRED)
>
> Save some modified file-visiting buffers.  Asks user about each one.
>   You can answer `y' to save,`n' not to save, `C-r' to look at the
>   buffer in question with`view-buffer' before deciding or `d' to view
>   the differences using`diff-buffer-with-file'.
>
> This command first saves any buffers where `buffer-save-without-query'
>   is non-nil, without asking.

You should therefore set the variable `buffer-save-without-query` to `t` (for example) for all your files. `(add-hook 'find-file-hook (lambda () (setq buffer-save-without-query t)))` should do the trick.

Comment: When I add `(setq-default buffer-save-without-query t)` to my `.emacs` file and then run the command `save-some-buffers`, it still prompts me with: `File to save in: ~/` (even though all my buffers have been previously saved to disk)

Comment: I do not understand what is your exact setup/problem.

Comment: I want it to save all those buffers without prompting. Now, instead of saving silently, when I do `save-some-buffers` or even `save-buffers-kill-terminal`, it prompts me with: `File to save in: ~/ `

Comment: Emacs is now trying to save all the buffers and not only the ones visiting a file. For example it is trying to save *Messages* and is therefore asking for a location. You just need to use `setq` in an appropriate hook.

Comment: I changed it to `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook  '(lambda () (setq-default buffer-save-without-query t)))` to my `.emacs` file and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: You cannot use `setq-default` this is what was causing the problem.